# Property 'error' does not exist on type '"" | Promise<any>'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to add some error handling to a service, following the Angular [guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#error-handling).

Relevant snippet:

```
private handleError (error: Response | any) {
  // In a real world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
  let errMsg: string;
  if (error instanceof Response) {
    const body = error.json() || '';
    const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
    errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
  } else {
    errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
  }
  console.error(errMsg);
  return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

However, I'm getting a TypeScript error:

`error TS2339: Property 'error' does not exist on type '"" | Promise<any>'.
  Property 'error' does not exist on type '""'.`

I can understand *why* it's happening-- `error.json()` returns a `Promise<any>` and then the subsequent line with `body.error` wouldn't work because there is no `error` property. However, it seems like it should expect a JSON object to be returned from `.json()`. Why is that, and what am I missing that the Angular guide isn't?

Comment: how is your import for Response looks like?

Comment: I don't have any explicit import, should I do so? It looks like when I cmd-click on WebStorm it goes to `JavaScriptLanguage/jsLanguageServicesImpl/external/lib.d.ts`

Comment: Just realized I needed `import { Response } from @angular/http`, without it I was getting the Response interface from JavaScript rather than the Angular-defined one that doesn't return a Promise.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Same thing just happened to me.  This happens when you fail to import the Response object.

```
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
```

Comment: What Response object must you import?

Comment: @adam-beck added it

Comment: Ah thank you! My IDE was recognizing Response but it wasn't the Angular one. That makes total sense.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't work because you wrote:

```
const body = error.json() || '';
```

Which means that `body` can be an empty string, and a string doesn't have the `error` property.

This should be better:

```
const body = error.json() || { error: null };
```

---

#### Edit

Oh, `error.json()` returns a `Promise`, which means that you won't be able to use this synchronous block, instead you'll need to:

```
error.json().then(body => {
    if (!body) {
        body = "";
    }

    const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
    const errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
});
```

Comment: The error is looking now at the Promise<any>: I changed the line to resemble:

`const body = error.json() || { error: '' };`

and now I have the error

```error TS2339: Property 'error' does not exist on type 'Promise<any> | { error: string; }'.
  Property 'error' does not exist on type 'Promise<any>'.```

Comment: Check my revised answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I finally found this solution.

```html
.catch(error => {
  let errMsg: string;
  const body = JSON.parse(error._body);
  if (body) {
    errMsg = body.error
  } else {
    errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
  }
  console.error(errMsg);
  return Promise.reject(errMsg);
});
```