# Getting a specific data from HTTP body response

Tags: ionic-framework, angular5, httpresponse

I am sending some data to my api by post and when it successfully submitted, it will return some data and I want to access the response data.

This is what I've got from my component :

```
this.http.post(this.restProvider.restApiUrl+'saveDraft', draftData, options)
.subscribe(data => {
   console.log(data["_body"]);
}, error => {
   console.log("Oooops!");
});
```

The **console.log(data["_body"]);** will resulting this data : 
`{"status":"ok","data_id":"2","statusMsg":"Saved as draft"}`

What I'm trying to do now is to access the value of `data_id` but I'm not really sure how to get it inside my component. I thought it can be accessed by something like `data["_body"]["data_id"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the issue by changing the `console.log(data["_body"]);` to `console.log(data.json().data_id);`

I refer to this discussion [Angular 2: How to access an HTTP response body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43394144/angular-2-how-to-access-an-http-response-body#45518630) and tried to apply the JSON and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think data is an object. Try this:

```
console.log(data._body.data_id);
console.log(data["_body"].data_id);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I tried it and it is undefined.