# How to console log a single value from JSON object in Ionic 3

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new Ionic and I am not able to access a single value from json object. I want to console log the value of timestamp which I get from API.

My TS code is something like this

```
viewTime(){

  let url = 'http://api.timezonedb.com/v2.1/get-time-zone?key=8304HG08VTGQ&format=json&by=zone&zone=Asia/Kolkata';

        this.http.request(url, this.config.options)
            .subscribe((response: any) => {
                   console.log(response);

                   this.data = response ;

                  console.log(this.data.timestamp); // i want this value to console log


                let date = new Date()
                 var myDate = new Date(new Date().getTime()+(7*24*60*60*1000));
                 console.log(myDate);

                 console.log("Current Date ",date);

                  this.nav.setRoot(AccountLogin);

                                }, (err) => {
                                let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                                title: 'Error',
                                subTitle: 'Please check your zone',
                                buttons: ['OK']
                                        });
                                 alert.present();
                                 });
                                 }
```

My API looks like this:

```
{
"status": "OK",
"message": "",
"countryCode": "IN",
"countryName": "India",
"zoneName": "Asia/Kolkata",
"abbreviation": "IST",
"gmtOffset": 19800,
"dst": "0",
"zoneStart": -764145000,
"zoneEnd": 0,
"nextAbbreviation": "",
"timestamp": 1538838621,
"formatted": "2018-10-06 15:10:21"
}
```

How to access timestamp value in console log?

Comment: console.log(response.data.timestamp); try @Saif khan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so here is the answer(map to json was missing)

```
let url = 'http://api.timezonedb.com/v2.1/get-time-zone?key=8304HG08VTGQ&format=json&by=zone&zone=Asia/Kolkata';

        this.http.request(url, this.config.options)
.map(res => res.json()) 
            .subscribe((response: any) => {

}

console.log(response.timestamp);
```

or

```
console.log(response['timestamp']);
```

should print the timpstamp.

Comment: Can you let us know what is  console.log(response); printing?

Comment: _body: "{"status":"OK","message":"","countryCode":"IN","countryName":"India","zoneName":"Asia\/Kolkata","abbreviation":"IST","gmtOffset":19800,"dst":"0","zoneStart":-764145000,"zoneEnd":0,"nextAbbreviation":"","timestamp":1538998984,"formatted":"2018-10-08 11:43:04"}"
__proto__: Body
constructor: ƒ Response(responseOptions)
toString: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object

Comment: this is the body of response which i printing.

Comment: i have defined data: any = {} ; in my ts file

Comment: couple of thing you can try here
1. map response e.g. .map(res => res.json()) or
2. try to directly access this.data = response._body

Comment: visit this one for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43394144/angular-2-how-to-access-an-http-response-body

Comment: thank you sir now its working..map(res => res.json()) solve my problem.

Comment: Great, I have updated the answer so It might be helpful for other as well :)