# Extract data from a redirected link in angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript, get

I am sending a http.get request and expecting it to return a value, let say x.
But the link is redirected and instead I get a 302 error.

When in network (web developer tools) I click on the original request, it goes to the redirekted link and the value of x is shown. Unfortunately, because x is in the new link, I cann't get it easily from response of my request. Does anyone know how I can get it? Thanks!

Here is my .ts file:

```
this.logingService.fun().subscribe(
            response => {
                this.x = response['x']; // I would like to get x value somehow like this, which doesn't work!
                console.log(response);
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);                
            }
        );
```

Here is my serivse:

```
fun(): Observable<any>{
        return this.http.get(url);
    }
```

Comment: What does your `response` contain?

Comment: This is the response: `HttpResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', url: 'https://redirectedlink', ok: true,}
body: false
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
ok: true
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: 4
url: "https://newlink"
[[Prototype]]: HttpResponseBase`

Comment: I guess you can use `response.body()` as described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43394630/17503046

Comment: Let me know if it solved your issue so that I can add it as answer

Comment: `response.body()`  gives this error: ERROR TypeError: response.body is not a function.

Comment: sorry for the mistake, `body` is not a function, it is a property, so is should accessed via `response.body`. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse#properties

Comment: No problem, `body` is false.